# HTML5 and Canvas: Moving background with player's movement

Tags: html, canvas, background, character

I am trying to make an HTML5 game using Canvas. I have a piece of code which supposed to move bg:

```
function drawScene() { // main drawScene function
clear(); // clear canvas
// draw background
context = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext('2d');
bgShiftX -= 3;
if (bgShiftX <= -100) {
   bgShiftX = 0;
}
  context.drawImage(floor, 0 + bgShiftX, 410);
  context.drawImage(city, 0 + bgShiftX, 175);
}
```

But I can't figure out how to make it move smooth and do not jump when it reaches -100px on X, so I need it move continuously. And also I want it to move when player press moveKey and reaches middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `keydown()` event listener for your moveKey. For instance, if it were the up arrow, you would write this:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ moveMe(e), false);
function moveMe(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === '38') {
    // shift up
  }
}
```

If you want it not to shift back to its floor value when it reaches -100px on X, then you'll need to start incrementing `bgShiftX`.

```
if (bgShiftX <= -100) {
  incrementX();
}
function incrementX() {
  bgShiftX += 3;
}
```

I hope this helps to clarify some things.

Comment: Thank you for help but now I get this: http://butkoalina.com/game/ It goes off the screen and deosn't want to be infinite...